# How to create a number range regexp grep filter from input variables

Tags: regex, grep

I have a relatively large amount of files inside a certain directory. There are always 4 types of files and each file type is numbered like so:

```
FileType<1-4>_<0000-9999>.ext
```

So, in the worst case I´d have 40000 files. Now, Im trying to write a simple bash script that filters out all files which are not contained in a range defined by user input, like for instance:

```
$ ./FilterScript 0 10
```

Which should output a list of all of the 4 filetypes going from the 0000 to the 0010. I have been working with grep and regexp and gotten some success. This is the example command I´m using to filter everything out (outputs from 0012 to 0023):

```
ls *.ext | grep -E '00[1][2-8]|00[2][0-3]'
```

Now the question is, how can I translate the user input to the script into the corresponding regexp expression, without manipulating the input variables as strings? If I want for example the range 90-120, the regexp expresion changes. Is this possible? I have tried using do loops, but in general I think the above mentioned command has a better performance.

Thanks in advance!
Ch.

Comment: By the way, the tool rgxg would be probably the best solution, but I need something that can be used in Windows using git-bash, with no admin rights.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'd guess it's because you didn't provide a [mcve] and/or you didn't run your script through http://shellcheck.net before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `ls *.ext | ...` - don't do that, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Regarding using a regexp to match a range of numbers - don't do that, use a numeric comparison.

It sounds like you should be doing something like the following using any awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v beg="$1" -v end="$2" '
    BEGIN {
        for ( i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
            n = split(ARGV[i],parts,/[_.]/)
            num = parts[n-1] + 0
            if ( (beg <= num) && (num <= end) ) {
                print ARGV[i]
            }
        }
        exit
    }
' ./*.ext
```

The above is obviously untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output for us to test a potential solution with.